# C# + SQL connection issue

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a problem with connecting SQL base with c# code. I have done the database and tried to display if my columns are visible, there aren't any problems, warnings, messages in visual studio, but i can't see data from my base. It is very simple database. I used those tutorial to do this connection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p2UeT7dBTEg] But, i have made one database. Here is the SQL connection part of the program:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {

    SqlConnection connection;
    string connectionString;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projekt1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }




    private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayBMI();
    }

    private void DisplayBMI()
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table ", connection))
        {
            DataTable tabelabmi = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(tabelabmi);

            listbmi.DisplayMemberPath = "bmi";
            listbmi.SelectedValue = "Id";
            listbmi.ItemsSource = tabelabmi.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your database table really named 'Table' ?

Comment: What is listbmi? Also check are you sure to assign DefaultView of table in your code to ItemsSource?

Comment: the way the code is setup...it would throw an error if applicable...are you sure its just that the table has no records in it...also are you just that mainwindow_load is attached to the load event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this. I moved DisplayBMI() to MainWindow() constructor.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

  SqlConnection connection;
  string connectionString;
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["projekt1.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    DisplayBMI();
  }

  //private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  //{
  //  DisplayBMI();
  //}

  private void DisplayBMI()
  {
    using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Table ", connection))
    {
        DataTable tabelabmi = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(tabelabmi);

        listbmi.DisplayMemberPath = "bmi";
        listbmi.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        listbmi.ItemsSource = tabelabmi.DefaultView;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If i change listbmi.DisplayMemberPath into listbmi.DisplayMember i have it underlined red the same is with the rest listbmi.xxx if i change it into what you have said, maybe it is about to add new references but idk which.

Comment: I can see the line where data should be visible, but they aren't.

Comment: I can see the line where data should be visible, but they aren't. ah it is srry my simple mistake, it works